# How to set as .DELETE_ON_ERROR a list of targets built by a static pattern in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

Having a `Makefile` like:

```
list_of_targets := $(PREFIX)/target1.xv    $(PREFIX)/target2.xv ...

$(list_of_targets): | dirs

$(PREFIX)/%.xv: %.sv $(src_dependencies)
    $(CMD) -o $@ $(params) $^

.PHONY: dirs
dirs:
    @mkdir -p $(PREFIX)
```

How can I make all the targets in `list_of_targets` `.DELETE_ON_ERROR`?

I have tried the following:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR: $(PREFIX)/%.xv
$(PREFIX)/%.xv: %.sv $(src_dependencies)
...
```

and

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR: $(list_of_targets)
$(list_of_targets): ...
```

and

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR: $(PREFIX)/target1.xv
```

This doesn't work either:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR: $(PREFIX)/target1.xv
$(PREFIX)/target1.xv: $(src_dependencies)
    $(CMD) -o $@ $(params) $^
```

**Note**: I have double checked that my build command returns `2` as error code. I have tried `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` with a simple test target and it works.

### EDIT 2

I have tried adding a `exit 1` to the pattern I'm executing and it does delete the file. It's like if `Makefile` could not detect the error returned by the compilation tool. But I'm sure it returns `2`.

### EDIT 1: actual Makefile (long)

Here there is a summary of my actual `Makefile`. It uses `Icarus Verilog` to build some fpga test benches.

```
PREFIX ?= ./build

SRC := ../src
SRCRV := $(SRC)/riscv
INC := ../include

TSRCRV := ./riscv
TESTUTILS := ./test-utils
RISCV_TEST_DIR := $(PREFIX)/riscv

CC := gcc
VV := iverilog

RANDOM := $(shell bash -c 'echo $$RANDOM')


tests := $(PREFIX)/mem_tb.xv                \
         $(PREFIX)/alu_logic_tb.xv          \
         $(PREFIX)/alu_add_tb.xv            \
         $(PREFIX)/alu_subs_tb.xv           \
         $(PREFIX)/alu_cmp_tb.xv

riscv_tests := $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/lw_tb.xv           \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/sw_tb.xv           \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/or_tb.xv           \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/and_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/sub_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/xor_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/sll_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/srl_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/sra_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/beq_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/bne_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/blt_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/bge_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/bltu_tb.xv         \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/bgeu_tb.xv         \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/addi_tb.xv         \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/jal_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/slt_tb.xv          \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/sltu_tb.xv         \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/jalr_tb.xv         \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/auipc_tb.xv        \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/datapath_tb.xv     \
               $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/controller_tb.xv

tests_waves := $(addsuffix .vcd,$(tests))

riscv_tests_waves := $(addsuffix .vcd,$(riscv_tests))


common_src := $(SRC)/alu.sv     \
              $(SRC)/mem.sv     \
              $(SRC)/utils.sv

riscv_src :=  $(SRCRV)/datapath.sv          \
              $(SRCRV)/riscv_single_top.sv  \
              $(SRCRV)/controller.sv


#
# Build al tests and execute them without generating wave dumps
#
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
test: $(tests) $(riscv_tests)
    $(foreach test,$^,vvp $(test) -none;)

wavedumps: $(tests_waves) $(riscv_tests_waves)

all: test wavedumps

$(tests): | dirs

$(riscv_tests): | dirs

$(wavedumps): | dirs


$(PREFIX)/%.xv: %.sv $(common_src)
    $(VV) -o $@ -g2012 -DSEED=$(RANDOM) -I$(INC) -Wall -Wno-timescale -DVCD="\"$@.vcd\"" $^

$(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/%.xv: $(TSRCRV)/%.sv $(common_src) $(riscv_src)
    $(VV) -o $@ -g2012 -DSEED=$(RANDOM) -I$(INC) -Wall -Wno-timescale -DVCD="\"$@.vcd\"" $^

$(PREFIX)/%.xv.vcd: $(PREFIX)/%.xv
    $(VVP) $<

$(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/%.xv.vcd: $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)/%.xv
    $(VVP) $<

$(PREFIX)/2scomp: $(TESTUTILS)/2scomp.c dirs
    $(CC) -o $@ -std=c11 $<


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf $(PREFIX)/*

.PHONY: dirs
dirs:
    @mkdir -p $(PREFIX)
    @mkdir -p $(RISCV_TEST_DIR)
```

Let's say I execute:

```
make build/riscv/addi_tb.xv
```

The above command is successful. Then I modify `riscv/addi_tb.sv` (dependency of the above target) to generate an error on purpose. I get this message:

```
iverilog -o build/riscv/addi_tb.xv -g2012 -DSEED=5478 -I../include -Wall -Wno-timescale -DVCD="\"build/riscv/addi_tb.xv.vcd\"" riscv/addi_tb.sv ../src/alu.sv ../src/mem.sv ../src/utils.sv ../src/riscv/datapath.sv ../src/riscv/riscv_single_top.sv ../src/riscv/controller.sv
riscv/addi_tb.sv:23: syntax error
riscv/addi_tb.sv:22: error: Invalid module instantiation
make: *** [Makefile:82: build/riscv/addi_tb.xv] Error 2
```

However, the above doesn't delete `build/riscv/addi_tb.xv`, trying it with any of the combinations exposed above. I have tried adding `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` at the beginning of the file as well.

Comment: Have you tried something like `.DELETE_ON_ERROR: $(wildcard $(PREFIX)/*.xv)`?

Comment: I tried it and didn't work

Comment: I don't see any `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` in that makefile.

Comment: I have put it at the top of the file, but actually I have tested it in other positions as well.

Comment: OK I see you edited your question and it's there now.  It doesn't matter where you put it.  It can appear anywhere.

Comment: It's clear that you've not included your entire makefile since make complains about the rule on line 82 and there are not 82 lines.  Maybe some other part of this makefile is causing the problem.  Maybe, for example, you are declaring these values to be `.PRECIOUS:`?  That will override `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:`.

Comment: No no, I deleted some of the targets to make it smaller and easier to read. I have now uploaded it literally as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` special target acts like a standalone boolean flag
for the entire make process and all targets in it.  It's not possible to apply it to a single target or subset of targets.  The docs say:

> If .DELETE_ON_ERROR is mentioned as a target anywhere in the makefile, then make will delete the target of a rule if it has changed and its recipe exits with a nonzero exit status, just as it does when it receives a signal. See Errors in Recipes.

It could be clearer, I suppose, but that's what it says.

Prerequisites are ignored, so I can't explain whatever behavior you are seeing, which you don't actually describe clearly.

Here's a test:

```
$ cat Makefile
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
foo:
        touch $@
        exit 1

$ make
touch foo
exit 1
make: *** [Makefile:4: foo] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'foo'
```

What part of this doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have added my actual Makefile and the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: I have re-tried it adding the `exit 1` you have and then it works. So it seems the problem is that `Makefile` does not detect the error returned by the compiler.

Comment: It definitely does.  You can tell because it fails: `make: *** [Makefile:82: build/riscv/addi_tb.xv] Error 2`

Comment: Thanks for explaining this limitation.  In fact, it is quite common to only want to apply to only a single rule/filetype and not the entire makefile.  Indeed you can parse the grammar to the documentation and literally conclude your results.  It is easy to think there is an omission because other similar looking stanza follow different patterns.  Explicitly stating it is global and extra arguments are ignored (and warn on them as being useless) would be helpful.

Comment: I would agree that there are other ways to structure the makefile to achieve this goal (so the functionality doesn't need to exist in Gnu make), but I don't think the documentation nor program behaviour (failing to warn) is supportive in making this 'global mode' transparent to users.

Comment: I definitely agree the documentation could be clearer.  I'm not sure I agree that it's a "quite common" requirement.  In fact I can't think of any other time someone asked about using this special target and wanting it to apply only to a subset of targets in the makefile.  Which doesn't mean it wouldn't be a useful capability, just that I don't think it's very commonly requested.